# What is meant by '550 Relay not Permitted' when it comes to emails?

Tags: email, spam, blacklist

For the past few months, I have been emailing a company with no problems.  They have been able to receive my emails and they have been responding.

A few days ago, they dropped me an email where my response was met with the following System Response:

> This is the mail system at host mail.example.com.
>
> I'm sorry to have to inform you that your message could not be
>   delivered to one or more recipients. It's attached below.
>
> For further assistance, please send mail to postmaster.
>
> If you do so, please include this problem report. You can delete your
>   own text from the attached returned message.
>
> The mail system
>
> : host
>       mx10.mailspamprotection.com[xxx.xxx.xxx.xx] said: 550 relay not permitted!
>       (in reply to RCPT TO command)

`mail.example.com` being my own Mail Server.

`support@domain.net` being the email address I am trying to send mail to.

What exactly does this mean and is there anything I can do about this?

I have tried sending the email from both Outlook and directly within the Server, where I am met with the same problem.

According to MX Toolbox, I am not listed in any Blacklists nor does there seem to be any problems with my SPF and DMARC Settings etc.  I also do not seem to have any problems sending or receiving emails with anyone else.

My communication is limited to emails, with this company, where I also sent them an email via their Contact Form on their website.  I have yet to receive a response, via their Contact Form neither; so I am not sure whether that was received or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This message "Relay access denied" or "Relay not permitted" means that the mail server received a message for a recipient at a domain that it doesn't handle email for, and it is refusing to accept it on that basis.

While mail servers *can* be configured to accept and relay mail for domains they don't serve, this is called an *open relay* and is very commonly abused by spammers whenever they find one.

In the instant case, the problem is not *your* mail server, but the recipient's mail server. The mail is apparently going to a spam protection service which, for whatever reason, has decided not to handle mail for the recipient's domain anymore. Maybe they didn't pay their bill. Who knows. But it isn't *your* problem.

Comment: It's possible the outbound server is not using DNS and has a fixed connector set up in which case the issue would be his rather than the remote end. This is unlikely however.

Comment: @Michael Hampton:  Great!  Thank you for this information.

Comment: @duct_tape_coder:  Thank you for your addition.  I have checked the DNS settings, where there are no obvious issues.  I suspect if it were DNS related, I would be experiencing a similar issue with other outbound emails.

Comment: @duct_tape_coder I think if it were the sender's smarthost, it would affect all outgoing mail.